# My file is not being copied correctly

Tags: c++, file

I am new to c++ and kind of learned on my own, so I have a program that is supposed to read in the specified file from a file path and *in theory* make an exact copy. My issue is that I am always off (as in off by bytes, Ex, a 173 kb file is 177kb), and from what I am seeing the bigger the file the more I'm off. So why I am I wrong and is there a better way to do it?

```
int main()
{

   //I was monitering memory usage, some reason if i wrote to console to fast, I couldn't moniter memory
   system("pause");
   ifstream inputFile;

   inputFile.open("C:\\Users\\Tallennar\\Documents\\Tables.docx", ios::in | ios::binary);

   ofstream outputFile;
   outputFile.open("word.docx", ios::binary);

   char buffer[257] = { ' ' };//one extra for \0

   if (!inputFile)
       printf("failed to open input file");

   if (!outputFile)
       printf("failed to open outputfile \n");

   //gets my file size
   inputFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
   size_t fileSize = inputFile.tellg();
   inputFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

   //some math to see how many times I need to loop
   int leftOverFromIterations = fileSize % 256;
   int fileSizeIterations = (fileSize - leftOverFromIterations) / 256;

   int bufferSize = sizeof(buffer);

   //loops through to print to output file
   for (int i = 0; i <= fileSizeIterations; i++)
   {
       inputFile.read(buffer, bufferSize);

       //so i dont get funny chars
       buffer[256] = '\0';
       outputFile.write(buffer, bufferSize);

       //for me to see what is getting printed
       std::cout << buffer;
   }
   //since not every file is divisible by 256, get the 
   //   leftovers from the above for loop
   inputFile.read(buffer, leftOverFromIterations);

   //close files
   inputFile.close();
   outputFile.close();
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `<=` should be `<`

Comment: Please define what do you mean by "_My issue is that I am always off_".

Comment: Also, you read the leftovers, but you do nothing with them afterwards, not even printing them to cout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems:

1. The `for` loop is running too many times, it should use `i < fileSizeIterations`.
2. You're overwriting the last character of the buffer with `\0`. You should set `bufferSize` to 1 less than the size of the array, so you don't read into the character needed for the null. Or you should use `std::string` instead of a C-style string.
3. You're not copying the leftovers to the output file.

You should also avoid hard-coding `256` throughout the code, and use `bufferSize` there.

```
int main()
{
    //I was monitering memory usage, some reason if i wrote to console to fast, I couldn't moniter memory
    system("pause");
    ifstream inputFile;


    inputFile.open("C:\\Users\\Tallennar\\Documents\\Tables.docx", ios::in | ios::binary);

    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("word.docx", ios::binary);

    char buffer[257] = { ' ' };//one extra for \0

    if (!inputFile)
        printf("failed to open input file");

    if (!outputFile)
        printf("failed to open outputfile \n");

    //gets my file size
    inputFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
    size_t fileSize = inputFile.tellg();
    inputFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    int bufferSize = sizeof(buffer)-1;

    //some math to see how many times I need to loop
    int leftOverFromIterations = fileSize % bufferSize;
    int fileSizeIterations = (fileSize - leftOverFromIterations) / bufferSize;

    //loops through to print to output file
    for (int i = 0; i < fileSizeIterations; i++)
        {
            inputFile.read(buffer, bufferSize);

            //so i dont get funny chars
            buffer[bufferSize] = '\0';
            outputFile.write(buffer, bufferSize);

            //for me to see what is getting printed
            std::cout << buffer;
        }
    //since not every file is divisible by bufferSize, get the 
    //  leftovers from the above for loop
    inputFile.read(buffer, leftOverFromIterations);

    //so i dont get funny chars    
    buffer[leftOverFromIterations] = '\0';
    outputFile.write(buffer, leftOverFromIterations);

    //for me to see what is getting printed
    std::cout << buffer;

    //close files
    inputFile.close();
    outputFile.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `getline()` instead?  A lot less confusing.

```
int main()
{

   //I was monitering memory usage, some reason if i wrote to console to fast, I couldn't moniter memory
   system("pause");
   ifstream inputFile;

   inputFile.open("C:\\Users\\Tallennar\\Documents\\Tables.docx", ios::in | ios::binary);

   ofstream outputFile;
   outputFile.open("word.docx", ios::binary);


   if (!inputFile)
   {
       printf("failed to open input file");
       return 0;  //if you didn't open the file don't continue
   }

   if (!outputFile)
   {
       printf("failed to open outputfile \n");
       return 0;  //if you didn't open the file don't continue
   }

   string line;
   while(getline(inputFile, line ))
   {
      outputFile << line;
   }

   inputFile.close();
   outputFile.close();
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

**Note:** I added `return 0;` to your if statements so it stops if it can't open the files.

**Disclaimer:** I have not run this code as I do not have a compiler that can deal with files off hand.